# Hi I am new in XSLT looking for solution to get value of image @href in multiple files in multiple dir i need to traverse till @fileref using xslt

Tags: image, path, href

Input.xml:
file1: root/section1/file1.xml

```
<p outputclass="text-center">
         <image id="arrangement_flow"
                placement="inline"
                width="400"
                height="400"
                href="images/arrangement_flow.jpg"/>
</p>
```

2nd file: root/section1/section2/file2.xml

```
<p outputclass="text-center">
         <image id="accounting_arrangement_flow"
                placement="inline"
                width="400"
                height="400"
                href="images/accounting_arrangement_flow.jpg"/>
</p>
```

Expected output:

file1:

```
<p outputclass="text-center">
         <image id="arrangement_flow"
                placement="inline"
                width="400"
                height="400"
                href="../../images/arrangement_flow.jpg"/>
</p>
```

file2:

```
<p outputclass="text-center">
         <image id="arrangement_flow"
                placement="inline"
                width="400"
                height="400"
                href="../../../images/accounting_arrangement_flow.jpg"/>
</p>
```

As far i archived this by using static variable ex: 'file///D:/rana/root' but need a  solution in dynamic way.